# Make img src changeable by a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, href, src

Adding an svg image using an img tag:

```
<img src="/photo1.svg" width="15" height="15">
```

I want src to be set based on a value. In this case, having an ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in parent.items"
    <img src="/files/photo1.svg" width="15" height="15"> 
</div>
```

Knowing that `item` has another attribute, `item.photo` which has as value a link: `/files/photo1.svg`, `/files/photo2.svg` or `/files/photo3.svg`.

My question is if it's possible inside the ng-repeat to make the src change it's value based on item.photo.

It seems that giving a variable to src is not working:

```
<img src=item.photo width="15" height="15">
```

I tried also with ternary but did not work:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in parent.items"
    <img src="item.photo === '/files/photo1.svg' ? '/files/photo1.svg' : 
              item.photo === '/files/photo2.svg' ? '/files/photo2.svg' :
              '/files/photo2.svg' " width="15" height="15"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-src`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in parent.items"
    <img ng-src="{{item.photo === '/files/photo1.svg' ? '/files/photo1.svg' : 
              item.photo === '/files/photo2.svg' ? '/files/photo2.svg' :
              '/files/photo2.svg'}}" width="15" height="15"> 
</div>
```

If you want to assign value of `item.photo` directly to `src` then you can simply do like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.photo}}" />
```